# How to force the iOS screen reader to spell out a word instead of read it?

Tags: html, ios, accessibility, wai-aria

In iOS, the accessibility screen reader is not spelling a word whereas in Android it spells out the word like I want. I have tried the below options with no luck. Also tried with punctuation marks between the letters.

`aria-label="N.K.E.P.X.1.3.5.K.L"`

I have seen that speak and speak-as properties are deprecated now and no longer supported on all platforms.

```
<span style="speak-as: spell-out;" aria-label="N K E P X 1 3 5 K L">NKEPX135KL</span>
```

Can someone show me how to spell the word?

Comment: Screen readers can do this using controls (SR BUTTON + left and right arrows normally). What is the use case for this as you probably don't need to do anything other than make sure that it is clear that this isn't a word (i.e. "your authentication code is:NKEPX135KL") so screen reader users know to read it letter by letter. It is also worth noting that `aria-label` will not work consistently on items with know semantic meaning / interactivity such as buttons etc.

Comment: Thank you, its a transaction ID so it will be generated randomly. As of now in iOS its reading like a word but in Android it's working correctly and spelling the word. I have verified everywhere but there is no luck. Also, I tried with <abbr title='x r g a q'/> tag but still its reading like a word in iOS.

Comment: @graham is correct.  Give the text some context so the user knows what to expect and then they can navigate the text letter by letter. Don't try to force the screen reader to announce things a certain way because you'll make it harder for braille users. Your example with punctuation or embedded spaces will be read exactly as you spelled it for braille users. So they'll read "N dot K dot E dot P dot" or "N space K space E space P space", etc